# jquery : fill and sort select from loop through multidimensional arrays

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I have two dropdowns, populated by a json. Onchange, I want the relevant info displayed.

See jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bf5u8/)

**Store 7** is present in both **City 1** and **City 2**.

HOW do I get **Store 7** to show on both cities without making another entry in the json?

I guess I need some kind of extra loop for the extra dimension, but I just don't figure out how.....I'm new to this...

Original loop:

```
    /* loop through array */
    $.each(data, function (index, d) {
        html.push("", "" + d.Type + "", "     " + d.Name + "", "" + d.Discount + "");

        $("select#place").append('' + d.Place + '');
        $("select#MyProductGroup").append('' + d.Type + '');
    });

    /* delete duplicates in select */
    var found = [];
    $("select option").each(function () {
        if ($.inArray(this.value, found) != -1) $(this).remove();
        found.push(this.value);
    });

    $("#MyDiscount").html(html.join(''));
```

My json:

```
    [{
        "Type": "Type 1",
            "Place": "City 1",
            "Name": "Store 1",
            "Discount": "10%"
    }, {
        "Type": "Type 1",
            "Place": "City 2",
            "Name": "Store 2",
            "Discount": "10%"
    }, {
        "Type": "Type 1",
            "Place": "City 2",
            "Name": "Store 3",
            "Discount": "10%"
    }, {
        "Type": "Type 2",
            "Place": "City 2",
            "Name": "Store 4",
            "Discount": "10%"
    }, {
        "Type": "Type 1",
            "Place": "City 2",
            "Name": "Store 5",
            "Discount": "10%"
    }, {
        "Type": "Type 1",
            "Place": "City 2",
            "Name": "Store 6",
            "Discount": "10%"
    }, {
        "Type": "Type 3",
            "Place": ["City 1", "City 2"],
            "Name": "Store 7",
            "Discount": "10%"
    }, {
        "Type": "Type 3",
            "Place": "City 4",
            "Name": "Store 2",
            "Discount": "10%"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are having a list of cities and the areas in which they operate.

why not store on unqiue keys.  First determine the key.... is it the store?  sounds like it.

so you could do something like:

```
{
"store 1":[{type,city, dicount} , {type,city,discount} ],
"store 2": [{type,city,discount}]
}
```

that way you will have an array of size 1 for most cases, but stores which server multiple areas would have multiple entries, for each area in which they serve.